# Calling zone.run in leaflet popup within Angular5 app

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular5, zone

We have an angular5 application with an embedded leaflet map.  This map binds a popup to various points which in turn open a details component.  This convoluted process works fine in chrome and firefox but is failing with an enigmatic "Syntax error" in Internet Explorer.  You can view the app at:
http://ptappdev.gisdata.mn.gov/ptappt

Click on any of the map markers and then click "view details".

In case it is a problem with javascript nested quotes I have tried a whole range of escaping patters.  Still no luck.  The code generating this popup is:

```
        layer.bindPopup('<p>' + feature.properties[Object.keys(feature.properties)[0]] + '<br /><a target="_blank" href="' + feature.properties['park_home_page_url']
      + '">open website</a><br /><a href="javascript:void(0);" '
      + 'OnClick = "'
    //+ 'alert(&apos;test&apos;);'
      + 'window[&apos;angularComponentRef&apos;].zone.run(() => {window[&apos;angularComponentRef&apos;].component.showResultDtlViaMapTip('
      + '&quot;' + feature.properties['name'] + '&quot;,'
      + '&quot;' + feature.properties['id'] + '&quot;,'
      + '&quot;' + feature.properties['park_admin_id'] + '&quot;'
      + ');})'
      + '" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; ">view details</a></p>'); // 1 initial load
  }
}).addTo(this.map)//.on('click', this.onMarkerClick);
```

The resulting html is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window['angularComponentRef'].zone.run(() => {window['angularComponentRef'].component.showResultDtlViaMapTip(&quot;Upper Sioux Agency State Park&quot;,&quot;530&quot;,&quot;spk00277&quot;);})" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">view details</a>
```

Any ideas on whether this is a syntax error with zone or a problem with my nested quotes.  Or perhaps something else entirely?  I would be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions have been introduced in ES2015 and [are not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) in Internet Explorer.

Your expression looks compatible with the use of a normal `function`, so simply replacing your arrow function by a normal one should solve your syntax error while preserving functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fix suggestion.  For reference, here is the new functional rewritten code, not using arrow functions:

```
<span onclick="window['angularComponentRef'].zone.run(function() {return window['angularComponentRef'].component.showResultDtlViaMapTip('Hill-Annex Mine State Park','210','spk00176')});">view details</span>
```